# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error with special signs URL

Tags: laravel, apache, server, special-characters

I have developed a Laravel API for my SPA. Sometimes I'm using query parameters to provide data to the API. But if there's an `@` sign inside the API URL the server responds with a `500 - Internal Server Error`. Example...

*Here I will get the error:*

http://www.mywebsite.com/api/user/login?name=example.user@gmail.de&password=changeMe

*Here everything works fine:*

http://www.mywebsite.com/api/user/login?name=exampleUser&password=changeMe

**Locally both ways are working. But when tested on the live server the error occurred.**

Does anyone know what the problem is? I'm using an Apache Server with Plesk, if it helps. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved the problem. If someone else has the same error:

Just set the server-sides default charset to `utf-8` fixed that problem!